# WAN port security assessment (DD-WRT)

Tags: router, security, routing, port, wan

I am running an Ethernet cable around my house to connect a cable modem in one room with the WAN port of the Netgear 6700 router (ddwrt) in another room.

I am wondering if this poses a security risk. 
Especially if an intruder could gain access to my LAN via that Ethernet cable that’s connected to the WAN port.

Is it possible to gain access to the LAN machines via the WAN port? If yes, is there a way to prevent that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Law 3 of the [Immutable laws of security](https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/) states:

> If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore

So if someone has enough access to your system that they can replace your modem or put their own hardware in, you are in much more trouble than simply being able to see your network.

That being said, it is a common thing to link a modem to a router via a WAN port. You could look at locking down MAC addresses maybe to restrict which devices can get on your network, or you could run some software on a server on your system to look at any changes of hardware/gateways etc on your network.